# How to code 'let timestamp: Date' to get May 10, 2018 10:00 PM

Tags: swift, date, date-formatting

In my dateLabel I am getting following result 2018-05-09 02:21:23 +0000.
In what place of my code I need to do 'dateformatting' to get May 10, 2018 10:00 PM. 
Thank you.

```
struct Model {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let timestamp: Date

    static func loadSampleData() -> [Model] {
        return [
            Model(firstName: "john", lastName: "doe", timestamp: Date()),
            Model(firstName: "alex", lastName: "doe", timestamp: Date()),
            Model(firstName: "lisa", lastName: "doe", timestamp: Date())
        ]
    }
}

class ModelTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    func update(with name: Model) {
        firstNameLabel.text = name.firstName
        lastNameLabel.text = name.lastName
        dateLabel.text = "\(name.timestamp)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Date formatter is very heavy object so do not make it local and try to reuse that object throughout the App. For that you can make `extension` of `DateFormatter` and make a static property in it for that formatter. Define all formatter in that extension. To use it simply anywhere in your app make extension of `Date` and use it.

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let shortDate: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a"
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension Date {
    /// Prints a string representation for the date with the given formatter
    func string(with format: DateFormatter) -> String {
        return format.string(from: self)
    }

    /// Creates an `Date` from the given string and formatter. Nil if the string couldn't be parsed
    init?(string: String?, formatter: DateFormatter) {
        guard let date = formatter.date(from: string ?? "") else { return nil }
        self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: date.timeIntervalSince1970)
    }
}
```

Use that in your `update(with name: Model)` method as:

```
let strDate = name.timestamp.string(with: .shortDate)
```

Now pass `strDate` in your label.
If you want to convert string in date use `string(with format: DateFormatter)` method.

Comment: You really should avoid using `dateFormat`. Using `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` will provide output that matches the format a user expects to see.

Comment: If there is another reason to avoid `dateFormat`?

Comment: That's pretty much it. You should never use `dateFormat` to present a date to a user.

Comment: Sorry. I have search but I didn't find any reason not to use `dateFormat`.

Comment: I told you why - it's bad user experience. Depending on where a user lives they expect to see a date and a time formatted in some usual manner. When you use `dateFormatter`, you are forcing the user to see the date in time in an unexpected and confusing format.

Comment: `dateStyle = .medium` and `timeStyle = .short` is giving required format but `at` in between.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170738/discussion-between-chanchal-chauhan-and-rmaddy).

Answer (score 0):

Use the date formatter in your `update` method instead of using string interpolation.

```
func update(with name: Model) {
    firstNameLabel.text = name.firstName
    lastNameLabel.text = name.lastName

    let fmt = DateFormatter()
    fmt.dateStyle = .medium
    fmt.timeStyle = .medium

    dateLabel.text = fmt.string(from: name.timestamp)
}
```

Set the styles to suit your needs.